# powershell winscp get local filename after transfer so i can attach to email

Tags: powershell, winscp

Hello I am trying to get the filename of the file just downloaded with the localpath ie C:\users\user\desktop\test.txt so i can attach it to an email. 
I am using powershell with the winscp .net library

here is the code

```
    param ( 
$localPath = "C:\upload\*", 
$remotePath = "/home/user/", 
$backupPath = "C:\backup\" 
) 

try 
{ 
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly 
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll" 

# Setup session options 
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions 
$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp 
$sessionOptions.HostName = "example.com" 
$sessionOptions.UserName = "user" 
$sessionOptions.Password = "mypassword" 
$sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session 

try 
{ 
# Connect 
$session.Open($sessionOptions) 

# Upload files, collect results 
$transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath) 

# Iterate over every transfer 
foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers) 
{ 
# Success or error? 
if ($transfer.Error -eq $Null) 
{ 
Write-Host ("Upload of {0} succeeded, moving to backup" -f 
$transfer.FileName) 
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Bc $Bc -Attach $session.GetFileInfo(Filename) -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
 # Upload succeeded, move source file to backup 
Move-Item $transfer.FileName $backupPath 
} 
else 
{ 
Write-Host ("Upload of {0} failed: {1}" -f 
$transfer.FileName, $transfer.Error.Message) 
} 
} 
} 
finally 
{ 
# Disconnect, clean up 
$session.Dispose() 
} 

exit 0 
} 
catch [Exception] 
{ 
Write-Host $_.Exception.Message 
exit 1 
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: This script uploads files. Was that a typo? Do you want the names of all the files that are uploaded?

Comment: i am trying to grab the file name while it is in the loop, it will send an email for every file

Comment: Is that not what you already have with `$transfer.FileName`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to use $session.getFileInfo() from the WinSCP library,  you're looking for $transfer.destination. I.e. `$session.getFileInfo($transfer.Destination)`.

Otherwise if you're reading the properties of the file from the local path, you could just use Powershell's built in cmdlets as such: `get-itemproperty $transfer.filename`

Comment: I tried that it didnt work. I got : The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again. I am not trying to use $session.getFileInfo() that was just my last attempt. I am just trying to get the local file after its downloaded with path so i can attach it to an email. for example if the last file was C:\users\user\desktop\test.txt and lets say it stored in $transfer.filename ( i know its not that is the remote file), i am trying to find what goes here -Attach (*right here ie $transfer.Filename)